# Any java http request validation library that can tell which input param field failed the validation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, http

> Request

```
{
    address: 
    {
        persons: 
        [
            {
                name: "valid"
            },
            {
                name: "in_valid"
            }
        ]
    }   
}
```

> Response

```
{
    which_field_failed: "address.persons[1].name",
    ... and more
}
```

Is there any validation library that can tell which input field failed the validation so that the frontend js client can highlight the specific invalid field on UI?

Comment: This can be handled at the front end right?

Comment: Let's imagine that the server is checking against a db to validate a field. One such validation is to avoid duplicate entries into db. So client cannot do this validation.

Comment: still here also,  you need to check the db for duplicates and include it in response and front end has to handle it.

Comment: yes, the frontend should parse the response from the server and then paint the UI with the error message accordingly. For that, the server should send out the right parsable error message like `address.persons[1].name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate bean validatior, If its a spring boot application check [this](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-validation-example/).

Or if it is "Vanila Servlet API" you can still use this by adding a request filter and implementing validation there using same hibernate-validator library. Check [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator-java-bean-validation/).